# Array for-loop and remove button php

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, unset

I have this code:

```
<?php
$animals = array('cat', 'dog', 'mouse', 'elephant');
for($i=0, $n = count($animals); $i++){
    echo $animals[$i]. '<input type="submit" name="remove" value="remove"/><br/>';
    if(isset($_POST['remove'])){
        unset($animals[$i]);
    }
}
?>
```

When I click on the remove button nothing happens. Any idea?

Comment: Are you trying to use PHP as how JS would be? -1

Comment: You're missing a lot of elements here, is this code included inside some other php containing a `form` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is also another approach that could be used

```
$animals = array('cat', 'dog', 'mouse', 'elephant');
if(isset($_POST['remove'])) $animals=array_diff($animals, array($_POST['animal']));
foreach($animals as $pet)
{
    echo'<form method="post" action="">';
    echo $pet.'<input type="submit" name="remove" value="remove"/><br/>';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="animal" value="'.$pet.'"/>';
    echo '</form>';
}
```

**Update:** (For the JavaScript solution you can use)

```
$animals = array('cat', 'dog', 'mouse', 'elephant');
echo'<form name="animalForm" method="post" action="">'; // action should be your this file name, i.e. 'pets.php'
foreach($animals as $pet)
{
    echo '<label>'.$pet.'<input type="button" class="remove" value="remove"/></label><br/>';
}
echo '</form>';
```

And this is the `JavaScript` code that could be used in the `head` tags between `script` tags like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload=function(){
        var btns=document.getElementsByClassName('remove');       
        for(i=0;i<btns.length;i++)
        {
            if(btns[i].type==='button' && btns[i].className==='remove')
                btns[i].onclick=remove;
        }
    };
    function remove(event){
        var e = event || window.event;
        var el = e.target || e.srcElement;
        document.animalForm.removeChild(el.parentNode);
    }
</script>
```

[**JS Demo**](http://jsbin.com/exedas/8/edit).

Comment: Thank @samuel and Sheikh,
I tried your codes, the first time I press the button remove an animal is removed, the second time does not delete anything, but replaces it with the animal missing. I want every time you press the button remove an animal is removed without replacement.

Here the pages:

[link]http://designnerd.it/prova/index.php

[link]http://designnerd.it/prova/index1.php

Comment: @AlbertoGrimaldi, You can't do it in this way because when you press the remove button it one item to the server to remove and your array is not saved in any way. I think you can use `JavaScript` for this.

Comment: Ok, can you explain how I can do? I have tried many ways, but I can not find the solution! thanks again!

Comment: I tried the update, but when I click on remove does not delete anything.

Comment: @AlbertoGrimaldi, look at  the [jsdemo](http://jsbin.com/exedas/1/edit), it's working.

Comment: @AlbertoGrimaldi, updated the answer and [demo here](http://jsbin.com/exedas/6/edit). It was a browser incompatibility with `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: @AlbertoGrimaldi, Oops! There was a typo, [fixed it](http://jsbin.com/exedas/8/edit).

Comment: Now I have another question

Comment: I want to submit the undeleted animals in another page... how I can do?

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you, but I'm a beginner and I would like to learn as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

if you are going to present "remove" as the value for each of the buttons, then the easiest way is to present an array for the `name attribute`. Once the `$_POST` is sent, you can iterate through the `remove` array and unset anything based off of the key.

```
<?php
$animals = array('cat', 'dog', 'mouse', 'elephant');
if(isset($_POST['remove']) && is_array($_POST['remove'])){
    foreach($_POST['remove'] as $k=>$remove){
        unset($animals[$k]);
    }
}

echo '<form method="post" action="./">';
foreach($animals as $key=>$animal){
    echo $animal. '<input type="submit" name="remove['.$key.']" value="remove"><br/>';
}
echo '</form>';?>
```

**Note:** There are many ways to achieve what you are looking for. This is one possibility.

Comment: Thank you Samuel! Your solution is good, but  the first time I press the button remove an animal is removed, the second time does not delete anything, but replaces it with the animal missing. I want every time you press the button remove an animal is removed without replacement. Sheikh Heera says I should consider javascript, what do you think? Do you have another method?

Comment: @AlbertoGrimaldi: It is because of forech loop constraint in item deletion.